# How can I solve this ODE using a predictor-corrector method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking to solve an ODE system for $y$ over time using the predictor-corrector method below. I'm not sure how predictor-corrector for ODEs work. I know other numerical methods for ODEs, like RK and forward Euler.

$\ y = 0$

Timestep (h) is 0.001s.

$\ \frac{dy}{dt}  = PI-QB \cos\beta\, $

Predictor:

$\ y(n+1) = y(n)+(\frac{h}{2}) [3dy/dt(n)-dy/dt(n-1)]$ is used to calculate $\ dy/dt(n+1)$

Corrector:

$y(n+1) = \frac{1}{3} [4y(n)-y(n-1)+2h dy/dt(n+1)]$

For the corrector, do I just substitute in the predictor instead of the $\ dy/dt(n+1)]$ on the right hand side of the equation?

Then $\ y(n+1)$ is $\ y(n)$  added to the corrector.
Is that right?

Link to my spreadsheet,  with my Predictor corrector formulas on the right hand side, that I think are wrong. - [Google Sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hjv9KDeLsT4G0GBk-hRpSPVmOx7wqrqf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Forward Euler is, among other classifications, a Runge-Kutta method. In your spreadsheet you have derivatives for 4 components, this is not really reflected by the formula in the question. Can you construct a code version of your method implementation?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was told by a professor it uses the predictor corrector method listed in the question. This is all he is able to say. I didn't ask about all 4 components in my question, as I believe that, like Forward Euler or RK4, if I can correctly implement the ODE of the predictor corrector method for one of the derivitaves, it will be the same formula to solve the other 3. I'll try to code it, but It may take a while, as I'm swamped with work.

Comment: The formulas, as they are, are somewhat strange. On the right side you should not have derivatives but function values. Only when determining the truncation error and thus inserting an exact solution are these function values equal to a derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for an ODE system $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t,y)$ the predictor extrapolates the existing data to the new point, here with
$$
\tilde y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac{h}{2}(3f_n-f_{n-1}),~~~f_k=f(t_k,y_k).
$$
Then the next solution point is refined with the corrector equation, here with the backward differentiation formula
$$
y_{n+1}=\frac13[4y_n-y_{n-1}+2h\tilde f_{n+1}],~~~\tilde f_{n+1}=f(t_{n+1},\tilde y_{n+1}).
$$
This correction step can also be repeated to get closer to the solution of the implicit step equation
$$
y_{n+1}=\frac13[4y_n-y_{n-1}+2hf(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})].
$$
This implicit equation can also be solved faster with a Newton-like method employing the Jacobian of $f$ or a locally valid approximation of it. This is done by most modern implementations of such implicit methods.

Comment: Arrgh, for some reason, I find the predictor corrector so much harder then any runga kutta method. Looking at that, I think my implementation of the method for each in the spreadsheet is correct after all. For the purposes of this exercise, I've been told that there is no need to repeat the correction step  for more precision.

Comment: Yes, one-step methods have a certain fire-and-forget mechanism in their stepper, in multi-step methods one has to manage a certain amount of step memory. PEC or PECE implementations are minimal and fast, but for the better accuracy and stability in stiff problems one needs to ensure the convergence in the implicit equation.

Answer (score 0):

Predictor-corrector are integrators which compute an estimation and then utilizes it to update the current value to the states of the ode. If you do this way, you will do it correctly.

Comment: Added a link to the spreadsheet, with my Predictor corrector formulas on the right hand side, that I think are wrong.